# IC chip identification request - Analog Devices

Tags: integrated-circuit, identification

[image]Please help me to identify this IC. I guess it is an Analog Devices chip

The signs say Q00 635

The oval line above with RA3 is an antenna, and this IC acts perhaps as detector (or amplifier) . The device is receive only - an electric field (EMC) meter and the displayed part is the E-field to voltage(?) converter.

Thanks

[image: Q00 635]

Comment: Show us more pictures of the PCB (zoomed out), so that we have a chance at deducing the chips function. Tell us everything that helps narrow down the search space: the voltages of the pins, the purpose of the device, etc.

Comment: Uploaded above. The oval line above with RA3 is an antenna, and this IC acts perhaps as detector (or amplifier)

Comment: Does the device only transmit, only receive or can it do both?

Comment: Petio, put all the information into the question rather than sprinkled through the comments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's an Analog Devices [AD8312](http://www.analog.com/en/products/rf-microwave/rf-power-detectors/non-rms-responding-detector/ad8312.html) 50 MHz TO 3.5 GHz, 45 dB RF Detector.